Texture output problem

I want to export the vrm model with texture to fbx or other format. But I found that the exported texture in texture file is not matched.
As photo1, the texture when I import the vrm have a (instance). When I use the editing and click on the texture(instance) , I found that there is another slot show some of the png are grouped to form a texture(instance).
And that when I change to fbx or even .blend, the texture could not be showed.
Is there any way to let the export model in fbx or .blend have correct texture showing?


.fbx export why there are no materials or textures
